# why does SuperSu need to be updated with every new OS version?

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, oneplus-3, supersu

I recently try to [update my OnePlus 3T](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/44d14602e9c30490513b9f5aa12300fb) and had some trouble (boot loop and freeze) as I was using SuperSU `2.79` to root it.

Everything was fix when I used `2.82` to root.

I realize now that I met this issue several times with different OS (CyanogenMod, OmniRom, etc.)

why does SuperSu need to be updated with every new OS version?

Why do I need to